# How to make sure that one syncronization block executes after the other

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

I have Counter class with 3 methods out of which 2 are synchronized, I want `increment()` to execute first and then the `count()`, so that count for each thread should always be 3000.

Instead of calling the `count()` from `run()` I can call it from within `increment()` is the only approach I can think of, Is there any other way to do So?

```
class Counter {

    int count=0;

    void print() {
        System.out.println("Print called by: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    synchronized void increment()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=3000;i++)
            count++;

    }
    synchronized void getCount() {

        System.out.println(count); 
        count =0;
    }

}

class MyThread1 extends Thread {

    Counter c;

    MyThread1(Counter c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run() {
        c.print();
        c.increment();
        c.getCount();
    }

}

class MyThread2 extends Thread {

    Counter c;

    MyThread2(Counter c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run() {
        c.print();
        c.increment();
        c.getCount();
    }
}

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Counter obj = new Counter();

        MyThread1 t1 = new MyThread1(obj);
        MyThread2 t2 = new MyThread2(obj);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Expected O/P in each case:

//The printing of "Print called by:" statement can be in any order as it's not synchronized but the count for each thread should always be 3000

> Print called by: Thread-0
>
> Print called by: Thread-1
>
> 3000
>
> 3000

Answer (score 0):

Working example for my comment  (You don't need MyThread1 and MyThread2):

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counter obj = new Counter();
        MyThread t1 = new MyThread(obj);
        MyThread t2 = new MyThread(obj);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class Counter {
    private final ThreadLocal<Integer> count = new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Integer initialValue() {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    void print() {
        System.out.println("Print called by: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    void increment() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3000; i++)
            count.set(count.get() + 1);
    }

    void getCount() {
        System.out.println(count.get());
        count.set(0);
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    Counter c;

    MyThread(Counter c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run() {
        c.print();
        c.increment();
        c.getCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, its working fine without even implementing the synchronization method and fully serves the purpose of my mentioned program but my main concern was related to execution order of synchronization method regardless of what the program is.

If there are more than one  synchronization block in an class then how can we assure that one  synchronization block should always execute after the other. Thanks in advance

Comment: @MayurJunior when you mark any method synchronized(or synchronized block on "this"), what this essentially means is that only 1 thread (with the lock on this object) can enter it. Also if you have multiple such synchronized methods/blocks in the same class still only 1 thread can enter any of these methods/blocks at the same time. so the order just depends on the order in which you invoke them (in the threads run() method). if you wish the threads run one after another (not recommended), you can either use the other answer or do t1.start(); t1.join() t2.start(); t2.join();.

Comment: I have the same understanding as yours i.e
" the order just depends on the order in which you invoke them (in the threads run() method) ".
But if you try to execute the program written by me in first place, for each thread the order of execution is different and random although I have mentioned increment() to be executed first and then getCount() i.e. sometimes the later gets called while for the other case increment()  gets first preference.
My whole point of asking this question at first place was that the synchronized methods should be executed in the order mentioned in run()

Comment: also for me the count problem was just a way to point the issue of order of execution of synchronized block i.e. I am least bothered about what code/functionality/computation/task we are performing in synchronized method. My main point of asking this question was to maintain the order of calls to synchronized method so if in my run() I have increment() to be executed first and then getCount() so these methods should be executed in same order for each thread and not in random order which is currently happening

Comment: @MayurJunior so indeed gede-wahyu-adi-pramana understood your question better. This is a classic thread-interleaving problem, what you wanted is atomicity between 2 methods, making them synchronized independently wont help and you will have to wrap the calls to these method as synchronized. There is another way to do it, provided another answer for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Counter obj = new Counter();

        MyThread t1 = new MyThread(obj);
        MyThread t2 = new MyThread(obj);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class Counter {
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    int count = 0;

    void print() {
        System.out.println("Print called by: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    void increment() {
        lock.lock();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3000; i++)
            count++;

    }

    void getCount() {

        System.out.println(count);
        count = 0;
        lock.unlock();
    }

}

class MyThread extends Thread {

    Counter c;

    MyThread(Counter c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run() {
        c.print();
        c.increment();
        c.getCount();
    }

}
```

Comment: Although I provided this answer just to show alternative way to achieve the atomicity between methods, I do not recommend it. You are better off synchronizing the calls to increment and getCount (in this example).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `synchronized` to block a thread.

here the example:

```
public void run() {
    synchronized (Thread.class) {
        c.print();
        c.increment();
        c.getCount();
    }
}
```

synchronized needs an object as param, please use same object for both class MyThread1 and MyThread2

read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html for more details.

Comment: In your solution the threads would run one after another not simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks @Gede Wahyu Adi Pramana , this seems to be working fine for me and I think no more synchronization keyword is needed for all the methods in Counter class as after removing also the code is working fine. 
Although I have a doubt what if there are 100 of classes calling the synchronized methods of Counter class then in class we have to add the synchronized block as suggested by you
Is there any fix then can be implemented in Main class or Counter class itself so that for each thread class we don't have to add synchronized block

Comment: Hi @joy , I am just learning synchronization, but isn't it the whole purpose of synchronization that once the thread enters the block should complete its task and then only the other thread should enter?

Comment: @joy Yes, that will be run one after another, as what MayurJunior asks. Afaik, one of the purposes of synchronization is to make sure only one thread can access a resource at given time

Comment: @MayurJunior Well in this answer the synchronization will give you the desired atomicity and isolation but it does so my making the whole process serial. So the 2 threads will not run concurrently (which is why you create the threads in the first place). else you could simple call the t1.run() and t2.run() from the main thread which is not what you desired. There are better ways to implement this concurrently, one of them is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html and it happens to give the example you are looking for.

Comment: @MayurJunior if you want to create more classes, I suggest to create a helper method that contains print(), increment() and getCount(). This requires all of threads should have same implementation

Comment: @GedeWahyuAdiPramana your solution solved my purpose but my main concern was related to execution order of synchronization method regardless of what the program is. 
If there are more than one synchronization block in an class then how can we assure that one synchronization block should always execute after the other. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: @GedeWahyuAdiPramana indeed you understood the question better than I did so if you edit your answer I will remove my downvote.